# Missing method exception when using Spreadsheetlight.SLFill.SetPattern

Tags: c#, spreadsheetlight

When using the method object.Fill.SetPattern(...) to tried to apply some background colour to an excel file that is being created with Spreadsheetlight, an MissingMethodException is thrown, which I can't understand the reason

I tried to look up in the developer documentation for possible problems but I couldn't find the solution

```
using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
        {
            sl.ImportDataTable("A1", dataTable, true);

            var style = sl.CreateStyle();
            style.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent2Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent4Color);

            sl.SetCellStyle("A1:Z1", style);

            sl.SaveAs(fileName);
        }
```

I expect the first row in the excel file, range A1:Z1, to be have some background colour.

Below is the exception:

System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void SpreadsheetLight.SLFill.SetPattern(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternValues, SpreadsheetLight.SLThemeColorIndexValues, SpreadsheetLight.SLThemeColorIndexValues)'.'

Comment: Can you post the full exception details?

Comment: I added it to the post now.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran your code and don't see any errors here is what I have

```
public void CreateDocument(DataTable dataTable )
{
   try
        {
            dataTable.Clear();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Marks");
            DataRow _ravi = dataTable.NewRow();
            _ravi["Name"] = "ravi";
            _ravi["Marks"] = "500";
            dataTable.Rows.Add(_ravi);

            using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
            {                  
                sl.ImportDataTable("A1", dataTable, true);

                var style = sl.CreateStyle();
                //PatternValues.Solid, 
                style.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent2Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent4Color);


                sl.SetCellStyle("A1:Z1", style);



                sl.SaveAs("Test.xlsx");
            }
        }
        catch (MissingMethodException ex)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to put the code inside of a method, whose parameter is the datatable?  I tried now to use another method in this class called "SetGradient" and it does work. Apparently, the program can't find only the method "SetPattern". I don't know why

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the code inside a method.